# echo add a newline between two strings

Tags: string, bash, echo, newline, quotes

I finally got to echo a new line between two strings in bash.
plus echo a string with an included \n.
as

```
m=$'line1\nline2'  
n=line3  
echo "$m" ""$'\n'"" $n
```

gives me

```
line1  
line2  
 line3
```

(I left the space in before $n to make it clearer.)
Is there a better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your shell, `echo` comes with a `-e` flag which prints escape characters.

```
echo -e "Hello\nWorld"
```

Alternately, you can use `printf`, but it doesn't supply its own trailing newline and you need to make sure placeholders don't appear in your text:

```
printf "Hello\nWorld\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `printf` to have full control on when you have new lines:

```
printf "%s\n%s" "$var1" "$var2"
#---------^^
```

For example:

```
$ s1="hello how are you"
$ s2="I am fine thanks" 
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "$s1" "$s2"
hello how are you
I am fine thanks
```